# Confused with `System.Directory` in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

I want to know if it is a problem only for me, and how to get through this.

I am now in the `$HOME` directory, and I can `touch aaa` to create one file.

Then I launch `ghci`. I can `import System.Directory` to import this package.

Now the problem occurs. If I try `doesFileExist aaa`, I will get `True` because it is really there. If I try `doesFileExist ~/aaa`, I will get `False`!!!

What is the problem then? Edit me if you find it is not clear. Thanks.

Comment: ~ is a Unix thing, you generally can't rely on programming languages other than Unix shells understanding it.

Comment: Then a follow-on question is, are there any packages that parse FilePaths like a UNIX Shell would?  That is they expand `~` and wildcard patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to expand a `~` like the shell does, you can define a function

```
expandHome :: FilePath -> FilePath -> FilePath
expandHome home ('~':xs) = home ++ xs
expandHome home path     = path
```

This can be called as

```
λ> h <- getHomeDirectory
λ> expandHome h "~/temp"
"/home/kqr/temp"
```

Comment: I will mark this as the answer even though other answers are good enough. I learned more from the answers.

Answer (score 7):

Haskell, like quite a few other languages, doesn't parse the `~` as home directory. ~ is just a common unix shell feature. So it's looking for a literal directory named ~.

Instead try

```
import System.FilePath.Posix
import System.Directory

homeDirFile :: FilePath -> IO FilePath
homeDirFile p = fmap (</>p) getHomeDirectory

main = homeDirFile "aaa" >>= doesFileExist >>= print
```

Comment: Yes, it is working. However, I don't understand what you mean since I can use `doesFileExist aaa`, and I am looking for a solution or explanation about how to let program understand "~".

Comment: @eccstartup You can't, Haskell doesn't parse ~ like your shell does. Instead you can use a function like `homeDirFile` that will add the home directory in front of some path

Answer (score 2):

The `~` expansion is not performed because it is a feature of the shell. `doesFileExist "/home/your-user/aaa"` should work. You might want to use `getHomeDirectory` from `System.Directory`.

Answer (score 1):

You can interact with system shell via [command-qq](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/command-qq).

```
> import System.Command.QQ
> :set -XQuasiQuotes 
> [sh|touch ~/aaa|] :: IO ()
```

And here you've got `~/aaa` file created.

Comment: It is an interesting package. I will check it out.